# how to prove a set is countable or uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The following sets are countable or not? Interpret you answer

$B=\{X\subset \Bbb N:|X|=2\}$

$C=\{X\subset \Bbb N:|X|\ne2\}$

For $|X|=2$ it should be countable because it only contains 1 digit over the set but for $|X|\ne2$ it's every natural number that isn't 2 so its uncountable?

Comment: Being countable and being finite aren't the same. The set of all natural numbers is infinite in size but still countable. A set is countable if it can be put into a one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers or some subset of the natural numbers

Comment: To show a set is countable, it is sufficient to find either a surjective map from a countable set onto it or an injective map from it into a countable set.

Comment: Generally speaking "I have no idea" questions are frowned upon here; see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). I suggest instead of asking six separate questions, you pick just one or two, explain what you have tried, and explain where you failed, and *then* ask what to do next.

Comment: For the second question: argue why it’s a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ thus it must be countable. For the third: creating the union of this with the previous returns the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ which is uncountable..

Comment: Just to get it out of the way: What do you think is meant by $|X|\ne2$?

Comment: @TonyK i thought it meant $]-∞,2[ u ]2,+∞[$

Comment: No! $|X|$ means the size of set $X$ (the number of elements it contains, if that is finite). So $|X|\ne2$ means that $X$ doesn't contain exactly two elements. How can you even be asking such a question if you don't know that?

Comment: so it can be $(a),(a,b,c),(a,b,c,e,.....)$ but it can not be $(a,b)$

Comment: That's right.${}$

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand the definition of countable, which as WaveX says "Being countable and being finite aren't the same. The set of all natural numbers is infinite in size but still countable. A set is countable if it can be put into a one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers or some subset of the natural numbers."  Some classes only accept infinite sets as countable, others include finite sets.  Second, you need to read the question carefully.  $\in$ as in the first one and $\subset$ as in the second are quite different.  The first is the set of real numbers whose log is rational.  You are given a bijection with the rationals by the set definition, so the set is the same size as the rationals.  Do you know if they are countable?  The second is the set of subsets of the naturals of size $2$, or the unordered pairs of naturals.  Can you see how this relates to $\Bbb Q$ in size?  The third is the set of subsets of the naturals that are some size other than $2$.  What do you know about how many total subsets of the naturals there are?